# CodingBat sameEnds dealing with Strings

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to do [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p131516) problem from CodingBat 
but don't understand why it doesn't work with input string "Hello!".

This is my code and below my code are the results I'm getting.

```
public String sameEnds(String string) {
        String result;
        int strLen = string.length();
        boolean isOdd = (strLen % 2 != 0);
        String start = string.substring(0, strLen / 2);
        String end;
        if (isOdd) {
            end = string.substring(strLen / 2 + 1);
        } else {
            end = string.substring(strLen / 2);
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (!start.equals(end) && i <= start.length()) {
            start = start.substring(0, start.length() - i);
            end = end.substring(i, end.length());
            i++;
        }
        if (start.equals(end)) {
            result = start;
        } else {
            result = "";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[image: Results I'm getting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are both incrementing `i` and using `start.length()-i`.  When `i` is equal to 1, the `start` variable becomes one character shorter. But when `i` is 2, `start.length()` is already one less than the original, and now you subtract 2 characters, so now you've missed one.  The same is true for the `end` variable.  Don't use both an incrementing `i` and the changing length of the strings.

To fix it, don't change the original `start` and `end` variables.  Do something like this:

```
    String sTmp = start;
    String eTmp = end;
    while (!sTmp.equals(eTmp) && i <= start.length()) {
        sTmp = start.substring(0, start.length() - i);
        eTmp = end.substring(i, end.length());
        i++;
    }
    if (sTmp.equals(eTmp)) {
        result = sTmp;
    } else {
        result = "";
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how come my code worked for the string "javaXYZjava" for example?

Comment: it just happened to work in that case because skipping letters didn't cause it to fail. But it would not have worked with an extra character like with "javaWXYZjava".

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems overly complicated.  Consider this:

```
public String sameEnds(String string) {
   int e = string.length() - 1;                  /* end of string */
   int b = string.length() / 2;                  /* where to start looking for a match */

   while (--b >= 0) {                            /* ran off the front yet? */

       /*
        * Starting just below the center of the string,
        * look for a character which matches the final character
        */
       for ( ; b >= 0; --b) {
          if (string.charAt(e) == string.charAt(b)) break;
       }

       /*
        * found a match to the final character (a possible starting point)
        * compare characters backwards until no match or all matched
        * (temp vars ee and bb walk backwards from e and b respectively)
        *
        *    "|f|r|o|b|o|z|z|Q|Q|Q|f|r|o|b|o|z|z|"
        *                  ^                   ^
        *                  |                   |
        *         <--bb    b          <--ee    e
        */
       for (int ee = e, bb = b; bb >= 0; --bb, --ee) {
          if (string.charAt(bb) != string.charAt(ee)) break;  /* no match */
          if (bb == 0) return string.substring(0, b+1);       /* victory! */
       }
   }
   return new String("");                              /* nothing matched */
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. I'm a bit of a beginner so my method's aren't the most efficient. I'm just writing the logic as it comes to mind.

Comment: @Nico the longer I do this, the more I believe that 90% of programming is really defining the problem.  Hopefully my comments and picture gives you an idea of how I thought about this one... How can there be a match?  To start with something must match the last character.  Where?  It has to be in the 1st half of the string.  Find one?  now start comparing... failed, ok look left for another char that matches the last char and repeat...

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's my solution

```
public String sameEnds(String string) {
  int mid = string.length() / 2;
  String ls = string.substring(mid);
  String result = "";
  int index = -1;
  int i = 0;

  if (string.length() < 2) {
    return "";
  }

  if (string.length() % 2 == 1) {
    i = 1;
  }

  // All we need to do is loop over the second part of the string,
  // find out the correct substring that equals to the origin string which start the index of '0'.

  for (; i < ls.length(); i++) {
    index = string.indexOf(ls.substring(i));
    if (index == 0) {
      result += ls.substring(i);
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: You should add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String sameEnds(String string) {
  //First half of the string
  String result = string.substring(0, string.length() / 2); 
  for (int i = 0; i < string.length() / 2; i++)
  {
    //check if first half equals second half
    if (result.equals(string.substring(string.length() - result.length())))
        //return result if true
        return result;
    //else remove last character of first half
    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
  }
  //return empty string if ends are not equal
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String sameEnds(String string) {
  final int len = string.length();
  String commonEnd = ""; 

  //Return empty for Anything smaller than size 1 or size 1 
  if (len <= 1) return commonEnd;

  //    S T R I N G
  //    0 1 2 3 4 5
  // left = 2, right = 3
  int left = len / 2;
  int right = len % 2 == 0 ? (len / 2) : (len / 2) + 1;

  while (left > 0) {
    //Start by comparing the string cut down in biggest halves and then keep squeezing
    //left and right from there on
    if (string.substring(0, left).equals(string.substring(right, len))) {
      break;
    }
      left--;
      right++;
  }

  return string.substring(0, left);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
public String sameEnds(String str) {

    int middle = str.length()/2;

    for (int i = middle; i >= 0; i--) {
        String left = str.substring(0,i);

        if (str.endsWith(left)) {
            return left;
        } 

        }

      return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Solution for same end intergers

```js
function solution(nums, len) {
    // if(len===nums.length || len === 0) return true
    for(let i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(nums[i]!=nums[nums.length-len +i]) 
                return false
    }
    return true
}

console.log(solution(([5, 6, 45, 99, 13, 5, 6], 2)))
console.log(solution(([1, 2, 5, 2, 1],0)))
console.log(solution(([1, 2, 5, 2, 1], 1))) 
console.log(solution(([],0))) 
console.log(solution(([1],1)))
```